# terraform code to delete objects in the bucket after 10 days

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have to delete objects in the bucket after 10 days. It means all the objects that bucket has more than 10 days older need to be deleted using terraform.

Wherever I found a code to delete it, it having prefix. What needs to be done if I have to apply to all the objects in buckets instead of prefix.

Comment: This is for AWS S3 bucket and below mentioned is the link that I have found for it.https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket

Answer (score 14):

You need to add expiration lifecycle rule (Note that prefix is optional).

Example:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b1" {
  bucket = "b1"

  lifecycle_rule {
    enabled  = true
    id     = "expire_all_files"

    expiration {
        days = 10
      }
  }
}
```

see [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket)

**UPDATE:**

On v4.0 and above the aws provider api changed and now adding expiration lifecycle rule looks like:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b1" {
  bucket = "b1"    
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "l1" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.b1.id
  rule {
    status = "Enabled"
    id     = "expire_all_files"
    expiration {
        days = 10
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Wherever I found a code to delete it, it having prefix. What needs to be done if I have to apply to all the objects in buckets instead of prefix.

As mentioned in the [doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#prefix)

```
prefix - (Optional) Object key prefix identifying one or more objects to which the rule applies.
```

Which means if you don't specify any prefix, it will apply to all objects.